# div table different cells per row

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if it's possible to create approximately the following table layout using only div tags and css only.

```
_________________________________________________
|           |                       |            |
|           |                       |            |
|           |                       |            |
|___________|_______________________|____________|
|      |       |                |                |
|      |       |                |                |
|      |       |                |                |
|______|_______|________________|________________|
|           |                       |            |
|           |                       |            |
|           |                       |            |
|___________|_______________________|____________|
```

The main problem I am having is with the second row. Having 4 cells throws off the widths of the first row with 3 cells. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="box-table" style="width: 800px">
    <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box" style="width: 20%"></div>
        <div class="box"style="width: 45%"></div>
        <div class="box" style="width: 35%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box" style="width: 15%">></div>
        <div class="box" style="width: 15%">></div>
        <div class="box" style="width: 40%">></div>
        <div class="box" style="width: 30%">></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box" style="width: 20%"></div>
        <div class="box"style="width: 45%"></div>
        <div class="box" style="width: 35%"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.box-table {
   display: table;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

.box-table .box-row {
   display: table-row;
}

.box-table .box {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: top;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

Is this possible, or do I need to make each row into a separate table? Thanks and appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible - [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/gepoyavase/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
.box-table {
  outline: 1px solid #c00;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 800px;
}

.box-table .box-row {
  display: block;
}

.box-table .box {
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  height: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Just as a quick follow up, how can I add some padding to the cells without throwing off the [rows?](http://jsbin.com/qodutewohe/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @paulorv you can 1) add an inner element to the cells and apply margins or paddings to it, or 2) increase the table size for the exact amount of total paddings (i.e. 5px of padding in a 3 cells row will add up to 30px)

Answer (score 0):

It's because each row should contain only the same amount of table cell. You can use colspan on the other rows except the second row, but you need to change div layout to table layout, which you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. Padding in your box class is causing a wrap. Remove this because it is adding additional width to the boxes (instead, add padding to a div within the div).
2. Add float:left to .box class